# Remove 'style=' from Tag Cloud

Tags: tags

I am attempting to style the widget tag cloud, however, it seems WordPress now adds `style="font-size: 8pt;"` automatically to the tag cloud class.  Does anybody know how to remove this?  Seems like a poor coding decision...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_generate_tag_cloud` has a filter that allows you to edit the string input. You can use regex to find and remove the inline style:

```
add_filter('wp_generate_tag_cloud', 'na_tag_cloud',10,1);

function na_tag_cloud($string){
   return preg_replace("/style='font-size:.+pt;'/", '', $string);
}
```